# How to prevent '+' from getting converted to space in Django request.POST method?

Tags: django

I'm trying to read an email-id value using request.POST.get(). If the post data contains email-id with a '+' symbol, like "example+something@gmail.com", it gets read as

"example something@gmail.com".

I know this is happening because the + symbol is getting decoded as space, but how do I prevent this from happening in this scenario?

Comment: I'm guessing you want to url-encode your strings something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547491/url-encoding-on-django-template?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @MLavrentyev That helped! Couldn't use urlencode filter as shown in the answer but I did something similar using js. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! The post data was not being urlencoded before being sent. For my scenario, since I was using Javascript XMLHttpRequest to post data, I simply replaced the "+" symbol with "%2B" using the js replace() function.

Another way according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/14830517/5918981 is to use encodeURIComponent()